# 別シートに、行列を入れ替えたデータを抽出する方法について

Tags: vba, excel

元データのシート（写メ1参照）から、完成形のシート（写メ2参照）を抽出するマクロVBA を作成したいです。

作業手順を日本語にすることはできますが（写メ3参照）、
マクロVBA でどのようなコードを書けばいいのかがわかりません。

詳しい方、どのようなコードを書けばいいのか、教えていただけると幸いです。
また、良ければ、どのようにExcelVBAに精通したのか、勉強方法も教えていただけると幸いです。
（今の私は、教科書的な一つ一つの作業（例.行と列を入れ替える、行と列を入れ替えたデータを別シートに抽出する、等）しかできず、実践の場では全く手が出ません。）

※追記
teratail, Qiita にて、似た題名の質問をしていますが、内容は異なります。
上記2サイトでは、本投稿での問題の簡易バージョンを質問しています。
（アルファベットと数字の混在したデータを、桁ごとに昇順に並べる方法や、
表を縦横変換した後、2つのデータの組を1つのデータの昇順に並び替える方法がわからなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきました。）

[image: 写メ1 元データのシート]

[image: 写メ2 完成形のシート]

[image: 写メ3 完成形の作り方（日本語）]

Comment: 他のサイトでもほぼ同じ内容の投稿をされているようですが [Qiita](https://qiita.com/Yukimiooo/questions/70e1d24574e9a25f25cc) , [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/308696) 、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 教えていただき、ありがとうございます。
teratail, Qiita では、本投稿での問題の簡易バージョンを質問したため、（投稿の題名は酷似しているものの）、マルチポストにはあたらないと勝手に判断してしまいました。その旨を付け加えます。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「簡易バージョン」ということはつまり内容は同じなのではないですか？

Comment: ご質問ありがとうございます。

Comment: 簡易バージョンという、誤解を生む書き方で申し訳ありません。
今回は、teratail やQiitaで以前質問した問題に加え、
アルファベットと数字の混在したデータを桁ごとに昇順に並べる作業や、
表を縦横変換した後に「2つのデータの組」を1つのデータの昇順に並び替える作業など
が加わり、前回の投稿で回答していただいたコードを応用しても解決できなかったため、
こちらで質問させていただきました。

Comment: 私は、初心者で、前回の投稿での質問内容をもとに、今回の投稿での質問内容を自分で解決することができなかったのですが、精通された方々から見てマルチポストに当たるのであれば、その旨を記載し削除します。

Comment: 数値と文字の混ざった文字列の桁数は全て同じ前提で良いでしょうか？ また、この質問は何かの課題のようですが、ワークシート関数やエクセルの並び替え機能等は使用できるのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。説明不足でした。
①数値と文字の混ざった文字列の桁数は全て同じです。

Comment: ②ワークシート関数やエクセルの並び替え機能等は使用できます。
ちなみに、この問題は、ご想像の通り、課題です。
VBAを用いず、個々の手作業とワークシート関数の利用のみで目的の表を作ることはでき、提出しました。
しかし、現場では建物名に当たるデータも、部屋名に当たるデータも数万あるケースを扱うと聞いたので、VBAでのやり方も知りたいと思った次第です。

Comment: 文字列から1文字ずつ取り出したり、（"b","a"）の配列を（"a","b"）にソートするコードは書けますか？　　現状では課題の丸投げの質問に見えますので回答は付きにくいかと思います。　【追記】課題は既に解決（提出済）だったのですね。VBAの課題というわけでもなかったのですね。”作業の効率化”が目的であれば、VBAに拘らずエクセルの使い方含めてアドバイスできることはあるかもしれません。ご自身はどのような処理をされたのかが具体的に分かればですが。

Comment: 自力で取り組んだ際は、
①元データのシート内に、建物ごとに、混雑具合について昇順に並べインデックス番号を付けた表を作る（手作業）
②横データのシート内のセルに、=IFNA(VLOOKUP($A3 & "_" & B$1,元データ!$F:$H,2,FALSE),"")式を入力する。

Comment: merinoさん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。自力で出来たところまでを投稿に追加して、出直します。

Answer (score 0):

この辺の記事を参考にして処理を作っていきます。

[指定した名前のシートが存在するかを確認する方法](https://bayashita.com/p/entry/show/192)
[シートをコピーして名前を変更する方法](https://bayashita.com/p/entry/show/191)
[第88回.並べ替え（Sort）](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba1/EXCELVBA388.html)
[縦持ちのデータを横持ちにする方法](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9485523.html)
[操作の対象セル範囲が不定の場合](http://officetanaka.net/excel/vba/cell/cell10.htm)
[最終行・最終列の取得方法（End,CurrentRegion,SpecialCells,UsedRange）](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba4/EXCEL222.html)

**(1)** の建物名ソートのルールは、普通の文字列ソートの考え方と一緒だと思われるので、特別な関数など作らずにEXCEL VBAのソート機能で出来るでしょう。

データを配列として取り込んで、結果をシートに書き出す方が早いらしいですが、私自身はEXCEL VBAの知識・経験に乏しいのでEXCELの機能を使う方向で作ってみました。
[VBA 縦２列を横３列(それ以上に変更可)に変換したい](https://teratail.com/questions/120202)

```
' 処理のメイン
Sub TransformTable()
    Dim i As Long, c As Range, wS As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long, h1 As String, h2 As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' 作業途中の表示をOFF
    
    ' "横シート"が存在するなら削除
    If IsSheetExists("横シート") Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("横シート").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    
    ' "縦シート"を作業シートにコピーしてソート
    Call Sheets("縦シート").Copy(After:=Sheets("縦シート"))
    ActiveSheet.Name = "WorkTemp"
    Set wS = ActiveSheet
    h1 = wS.Cells(1, "B") ' 列名の基を記憶
    h2 = wS.Cells(1, "C") ' 列名の基を記憶
    With wS.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=wS.Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending   ' 建物名を昇順
            .Add Key:=wS.Range("C1"), Order:=xlDescending  ' 混雑割合を降順
        End With
        .SetRange wS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

    ' "横シート"を作成し、作業シート内容を並び替えてコピー
    Call Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("縦シート"))
    ActiveSheet.Name = "横シート"
    Set wS = ActiveSheet
    wS.Cells.ClearContents
    With Worksheets("WorkTemp")
        .Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=wS.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set c = wS.Range("A:A").Find(what:=.Cells(i, "A"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            wS.Cells(c.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = .Cells(i, "B") ' 部屋(右方向に拡張して設定)
            wS.Cells(c.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = .Cells(i, "C") ' 混雑割合(上記に同じ)
        Next i
    End With
    
    ' データの存在する分だけ列名+番号を設定
    x = (wS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 1) / 2
    For i = 1 To x
        wS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = h1 + str(i) ' 部屋 + 列番号
        wS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = h2 + str(i) ' 混雑割合 + 列番号
    Next i

    ' 作業シートを削除
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("WorkTemp").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  ' 表示を再開
    wS.Activate

End Sub

' 名前でシートが存在するかチェック
Function IsSheetExists(strSheetName As String)
    Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo NotExists
    
    Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSheetName)
    IsSheetExists = True
    Exit Function
NotExists:
    IsSheetExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: kunifさん
参考サイトをあげていただけたことで、このように問題を細分化して、取り組めばいいのだと分かりました。未知の問題に遭遇したときに、どのように既知をつなげて考えていくのか、ヒントをいただけました。ありがとうございます。